# NSConcreteValue valueForUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, iphone, calayer, key-value-observing

This happens when I start the application and taps rapidly on the screen while starting. I have no clues in the stacktrace since its all inside the framework. I'm fearing it might have something to do with ReactiveCocoa 2.0.

Error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteValue 0x40857fe0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key x_60288.'
```

Stack trace

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x036c45e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x034478b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x037546a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
3   Foundation                          0x015b98ca -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
4   Foundation                          0x01526921 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 81
5   Foundation                          0x01525f5b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 260
6   Foundation                          0x01545a02 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 321
7   QuartzCore                          0x02379bfb CAObject_valueForKeyPath_ + 2797
8   QuartzCore                          0x02379ead CAObject_valueForKeyPath + 147
9   QuartzCore                          0x0235ff4f -[CALayer valueForKeyPath:] + 24
10  UIKit                               0x0262da96 _UIViewLayerAnimationCanBeConsideredFinished + 91
11  UIKit                               0x026161c5 __22-[UIWindow sendEvent:]_block_invoke + 36
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0374105d __53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 61
13  CoreFoundation                      0x03740f92 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 258
14  CoreFoundation                      0x036be0a5 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:] + 53
15  UIKit                               0x02615fa3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 751
16  UIKit                               0x025e9e86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
17  UIKit                               0x025d418f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0364d83f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0364d1cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0366a29e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
21  CoreFoundation                      0x03669ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
22  CoreFoundation                      0x036698db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
23  GraphicsServices                    0x04c729e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
24  GraphicsServices                    0x04c72809 GSEventRun + 104
25  UIKit                               0x025d6d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
26  IVYCore                             0x00003242 main + 178
27  IVYCore                             0x00003185 start + 53
```

This answer is not a duplicate because

- the source is unknown
- the key is unknown
- caused automatically by the frameworks
- no explicit clues

Comment: Have you searched all project files for `x_60288`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes. No reference to it, and it changes all the time.

Comment: Have you found the reason?

Comment: Yes, I've been looking for the answer for 6 years and 341 days. I finally found the answer. It was sitting right in front of the me the whole time!